# How do I fix this EOF error on python 3 version

Tags: python-3.x

I am working on a very basic problem on Hackerrank.

**Input format:**

First line contains integer N.

Second line contains string S.

**Output format:**

First line should contain N x 2.

Second line should contain the same string S.

**sample test case**

5

helloworld

**my code is as: (on PYTHON 3)**

```
n=int(input())
s=input()

print(2*n)
print(s)
```

I am getting error:

```
Execution failed.
EOFError : EOF when reading a line

Stack Trace:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/tmp/143981299/user_code.py", line 1, in <module>
N = int(input())
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
```

I tried this method to take input many times and this is the first time I am having this error. Can anyone please explain why?

Comment: It works fine, try another text editor (im using notepad++) or check if you have misplaced indentations on your code

Comment: Why is the error message "line 11" when you have 5 lines of code and the called out line is line 1?   I suspect an issue with code input.

Comment: @MarkTolonen I copied this error msg from IDE in which first few lines were some instructions comments.

Comment: @RedZ but how to solve this in hackerrank? this is my question.

Comment: Maybe delete the comments and leave just your code, which looks correct.

Comment: @MarkTolonen tried it. no luck. updated the error here.

Answer (score 0):

use a try/except block to handle the error

```py
while True:
    try:
        n=int(input())
        s=input()
        print(2*n)
        print(s)
    
    except:
        break
```